# Check if String contains String - Java

Tags: java

I have a String[] with some tags.

In my example: `image.getRepoTags[0] = clone_envx:img1` and `imageTag = img1`

My code returns false. Why ? How to do check if `imageTag is in String[] image.getRepoTags()?`

```
 if(Arrays.asList(image.getRepoTags()).contains(imageTag))
       return true;
  else
       return false;
```

Comment: there is a difference between `list.contains()` and `string.contains()`. that is your problem here. the first checks if there are exact matches of the whole object, while the second checks for the actual content of the strings

Comment: @XtremeBaumer can you give me an example how would I fix this?

Comment: If `imageTag = " clone_envx"` It must return true? and It 's `"tag1:tag2:tag3:img1"` a valid value of `getRepoTags()[0]` ?

Comment: made a java 7 solution. although we have some valid java 8 versions too

Comment: If `imageTag = " img"` It must return `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `list.contains()` and `string.contains()`. That is your problem here. The first checks if there are exact matches of the whole object, while the second checks for the actual content of the strings.

Example for `list.contains()`:

```
new String[]{"test", "test2", "img1"}
```

contains the actual string object `img1` (true). If we change the array to

```
new String[]{"test", "test2", "clone_envx:img1"}
```

then it doesn't contain a perfect match (false).

Java 7 solution to the problem:

```
for (String str : image.getRepoTags()) {
    if(str.contains(imageTag)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

the second return should only happen after iterating the whole list. That is the reason it is after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the array into List will not help you to address your need as you want to search inside the `String` elements.

You could iterate the array elements and stop as soon as one element contains `imageTag`:

```
return  Arrays.stream(arr)
              .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("imageTag"));
```

Comment: IMHO it's better: return `Arrays.stream(image.getRepoTags())
                                                 .anyMatch(s -> s.contains(imageTag));`

Comment: @ David Pérez Cabrera Much simpler indeed.  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You should loop or stream the list of tags and check if any of them contains your imageTag variable.

For example in Java 8:

```
    boolean anyMatch = Arrays.asList(image.getRepoTags()).stream()
                            .anyMatch(tag -> tag.contains("img1"));
```

Comment: you can directly return the value `return Arrays.asList(image.getRepoTags()).stream().anyMatch(tag -> tag.contains(imageTag)) ? true : false;`